# Pandas find second sentence in data and replace it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm basically trying to find if there is any second sentence in data. If there a second sentence I want to collect second sentence and write again below previous(first sentence) one. But im confused.

Note: I check the commas to check if there is a second sentence, and if there is a second sentence in my data, there are coming after commas.

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    "Image Src": ["link1.jpg", "link2.jpg, link3.jpg", "link4.jpg", "link5.jpg, link6.jpg"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create an empty list to store extra sentences
extra_sentences = []

# Extract extra sentences after commas
for i in range(len(df)):
    # Split the string on commas
    image_src, *sentences = df.loc[i, "Image Src"].strip().split(",")
    
    # Collect sentences after commas
    if sentences:
        extra_sentences.extend(sentences)  # Use extend to add all sentences

    # Update DataFrame with cleaned image src (without commas)
    df.loc[i, "Image Src"] = image_src.strip()

# Print the collected extra sentences (optional)
print("Extra Sentences:")
for sentence in extra_sentences:
    print(sentence.strip())

# Print the modified DataFrame (optional)
print("\nModified DataFrame:")
print(df)
```

Comment: `out = df.assign(**{'Image Src': lambda d: d['Image Src'].str.split(', *')}).explode('Image Src')`